# Hiding bookmarks pane in Beamer

Tags: beamer

When I open the compiled pdf file, the bookmark pane is displayed to the left of the slides. How to avoid displaying this pane in the initial view? I am using the following preamble

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `beamer` loads package `hyperref` for the bookmarks (and other hyper features). Option `pdfpagemode` is the option for the initial page mode:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone}
```

Of course, it depends on the PDF viewer, if it respects that setting (Adobe Reader does, xpdf does not).

Comment: Alternatively the option can be passed when loading beamer: `\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=UseNone}]{beamer}`

Comment: @samcarter And there is `\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagemode=UseNone}{hyperref}` before `\documentclass{beamer}`.

Comment: Now the OP has the "Qual der Wahl" :)